# Simple AWS Lambda response is null if callback is called in different context

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I was having problems running some code I wrote using AWS Lambda with NodeJS. It took me some time to narrow my issue down but eventually I noticed that if I call the callback function from a different context than the context of handler function, then the response value is null.

Here's the simple function I used to test that

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  callback (null,{
        statusCode: 201,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/html"
        },
        body: {}
  });
}
```

If I run a test event with this code (test script is an empty JSON) then the result is simply:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 201,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "text/html"
  },
  "body": {}
}
```

**However** if I only force the callback function to be called in a different context as in the example below:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {    
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback (null,{   // <-- callback is now called in timer context
            statusCode: 201,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "text/html"
            },
            body: {}
      })}, 5000);
}
```

Then running the exact same test event (empty JSON) now results in a null response:

```
Response:
null
```

Now this seems to me like a very basic functionality, I just assume I am missing something here. Can anyone help pinpoint my error? or explain how the response value can contain the required values even if callback is called in a different context??
Thanks!

[image: Synchronous code with working result]
[image: Asynchronous code with null response]
[image: Test event - empty JSON object]

**Update #1**
Tested one more time with the use of a promise:

[image: Another test with promise]

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This totally depends on how you use the function. It doesn't depend on a 'context'. Snippet 1 is synchronous. Snippet 2 is asynchronous. You don't use promises, so `async` doesn't do any good.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but how does that lack any information? I mentioned that I only test it with the built-in test event functionality in Lambda using an empty JSON object. You can literally recreate it your self in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: And yes, you are right - one version is synchronous and the other is asynchronous. I expected both to work but the asynchronous method does not. I have no idea why and that is why I'm asking here for help

Comment: I see, so the function is fed directly to Lambda. I don't use Lambda myself but I would expect it to understand `callback` parameter in this case. Did you try to stick to promises and return a value from `async` instead of using a callback?

Comment: Thanks @estus I just tried using a promise and added a screenshot of that as well to the question details (at the bottom). It still does not work and response is null...

Comment: It doesn't return a promise and still involves a callback. I'd expect it to be something like `exports.handler = async (event, context) => { await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r)); return { statusCode: ... }; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will return immediately before the callbacks are invoked. That's why it works in the first example.

Try adding `await` to the front of your `Promise` example so that node completes the work before moving on.

```
const value = await delay(5000)
callback(null, value)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding the await as you suggest. I edited your suggested code a little to what I tried and it indeed worked. So thanks! Now I will try to apply this to my original problem and see how that works :)